# Dapper strange behaviour with datetime2

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dapper

I'm using Dapper and I have a simple class:

```
public class Person 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime LastModificationDate { get; set; }
}
```

In my SQL Server database, I have a table `Person`:

```
Id (int)
LastModificationDate (DateTime2)
```

Now I perform select:

```
var sql = select * from Person 
var persons = connection.Query<Person>(sql).ToList()
```

Problem is that `LastModificationDate` doesn't contain milliseconds. How it can be fixed?

Comment: What's the **exact** datatype of `LastModificationDate` in SQL Server? `DATETIME2(n)` support values for `n` (digits *after* the seconds) from 0 to 7 - if you use `DATETIME2(0)`, then the accuracy is to the second - no fractions of seconds are being stored.

Comment: Also, just to stave off the obvious -- how have you verified "it doesn't contain milliseconds"? The default formatting of `DateTime` when displayed as a string doesn't normally show any milliseconds; you need an explicit formatting string with `fff` for that.

Comment: Ok I just had to add:

SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(DateTime), System.Data.DbType.DateTimeOffset);

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(DateTime), System.Data.DbType.DateTimeOffset);
```

Comment: You didn't answer any of the comments above for clarification. I'm going to say this might appear to work, but isn't the solution you need. That said, ideally the Database is DatetimeOffset(7), and then your entity / model also uses DatetimeOffset. This way you store not only the milliseconds but timezone information too. I suspect your problem though is really more of a format / culture issue...